# How to detect and replace values/parameters in URL on redirection

Tags: javascript, java, php, arrays

For clarification of my question, let me specify everything,

There are three links (link A and Link B and Link C)

**link A is:**
https://abc.mdx.com/p?id={c_val}

**link B is:**
https://def.xyz.net/c?c_val={id}

**Link C is:** 
https://ajddf.com/adfadfdfa4564

In my database I have a value **adgaf7g6adf6gadfg8a86fgs9f6g**

Now coming to main point, when someone redirects from link C
I want to pass **adgaf7g6adf6gadfg8a86fgs9f6g** in Link A

Comment: Very unclear what you are trying to ask here. Is `{c_val}` supposed to be some sort of placeholder syntax, and you want to know how to replace it with a value, when you got this whole URL in a string variable or something? What do the tags `javascript` and `arrays` have to do with this?

Comment: How indeed? What is `{c_val}` supposed to represent and how do you propose it gets populated?

Comment: Fellas, I am saying, suppose i have a GET parameter &c_val=
and i whatever i fetch in that, 
when i use {c_val} token/parameter, it just detects the value from DB and pass in the url in below format
https://abc.xyv.com/p?id={c_val}

id= here is to pass {c_val} to third party

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
var url_string = window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
var id = url.searchParams.get("id");
window.location.replace("www.redirectaddress.com/p?id="+id); //redirect
```

Comment: Fellas, I am saying, suppose i have a GET parameter &c_val=
and i whatever i fetch in that, 
when i use {c_val} token/parameter, it just detects the value from DB and pass in the url in below format
https://abc.xyv.com/p?id={c_val}

id= here is to pass {c_val} to third party

Comment: yes, so you just need to take the value from the url and append it as a string to the new url string to pass to the third party.